# Matlab - how to put the same number of decimal places in the axes

Tags: charts, matlab, axis

How can I put all the axis numbers with the same number of decimal places on the chart? I want all y-axis numbers to have the same number of decimal places. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by [**`get`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html)ting the `ytick`s, converting them to string with required number of decimal digits using [**`num2str`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), and then [**`set`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html)ting them as `yticklabels`.

So just add the following line after plotting:

```
set(gca,'yticklabel',num2str(get(gca,'ytick')','%.3f')); 
%This will set all values on the y-axis to 3 decimal places
```